# static variables, libgdx and android pause/resume memory usage

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Program example:

```
public class main extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    public static int a;
    public static int b;
    public static Player player;

    public void create()
    {
        resume();
    }

    public void render()
    {
    }

    public void resize()
    {
    }

    //pause runs when home button is pressed
    public void pause()
    {
        player = null;
    }

    //resume runs when the program is re-opened
    public void resume()
    {
        a = 10;
        b = 20;
        player = new Player();
    }
}
```

On android, when the home button is pressed, the program is kept in memory and static variables keep their values.  Now when this program is re-opened, does this example create new static variables or just assign values to the old static variables that were in memory?

I'm asking because I have a program that has an issue where pressing home and re-opening the program results in the memory increasing each time and I'm wondering if this could play a role in why that occurs.

updated: Does the player object get removed from memory when it is declared null before getting created again?

Comment: Run the debugger and see what happens. Best way to find out IMO

Answer (score 2):

The life-cycle of static references is not the same as the life-cycle of your application. In other words, it is possible that multiple instances of your application use the same static variable.

If you set a static variable to `null` in a method of your application then you will set it to `null` for all instances of your application running in the same VM. Setting a reference to `null`, however does not mean that the memory is actually free'd. Only when there are no other references to the same object and the garbage collector is run, then the object will removed.

That said, please note that the `pause` and `resume` methods are not the correct methods to do something like that. In fact, for above reasons you should never use the `static` keyword at all for things that are specific to one instance of your application, unless you are properly managing those `static` references. For example, libgdx does this behind the scenes by keeping a map of the instances of your application and the resources they use. This allows you to have "managed resources" which are automatically reloaded when needed (which is the default).

In your case that would be over complicating things and it's easier to simply remove the `static` keyword. This typically also forces you to have a better OO design as well and not use shortcuts like e.g. the singleton pattern which will usually lead to other issues on the long run as well.

Answer (score 0):

**create new static variables** or just **assign values to the old static variables** that was is in memory ?

Only assign value to `a`, `b` by `resume()` method.

**Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution.**

**EDIT**

You're creating new object of `Player` and assigning to `player` reference  variable. After that you don't have reference of old player object so when JVM feel need to run garbage collector, garbage collector will run and clear memory of old player object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is initially what I thought but I figured I might be wrong.  What about the static object?  I guess I updated my question after you responded.

Comment: I think making object in `resume()`, don't make sense.

Comment: In a program I am writing, my memory allocation increases every time home is pressed and then the program is re-opened.  It increases by about 1.5 - 2 MB each time.  The program starts at about 5 MB allocated and I've gone up to about 16 MB using home/re-open.  I've tried even forcing the garbage collector to run but it doesn't bring down the memory allocated.  Would the garbage collector drop the memory allocated instantly which means I do have a memory issue or does it do it in it's own time and perhaps an issue is not present?  If you don't know then that's fine.  Just figured I'd ask.

Comment: Are you creating objects in `resume()`, I think `resume()` is not right place for creation of objects ?

Comment: In response to your edited answer regarding player object.  The Player object is static so wouldn't the garbage collector not remove the old reference to player object due to it being static? I know that static objects and variables remain in memory for the entire time the program runs but I'm not sure how the garbage collector deals with old references of static objects and variables.

Comment: Yes I do create an object in resume(). I have my assests class as a singleton in my game and I set it to null in pause() and I re-create it in resume().  I used to have it in create() but on android, I ran into problems with the pause() and resume() methods and found that calling resume() from create() solved the issue.  The issue was that when the game re-opened, resume() was not being called for some unknown reason.  Create() was called and then render() so that is why I just put a call to resume() in create().

Comment: only reference is static so when old `player` object dereferenced, it'll collectable. You need to create objects in `create()` or in `show()` if you're in Screen. You're making null so each time object created for your singleton Class

Comment: Yes I have to create that class every time when the game loads as it holds all of my textures, sounds, music, etc.  When home is pressed, the textures would disappear when re-opening the game.  So the object creation for that, has to go in resume().  Unless there is some other way to manage textures that I'm unaware of whereby they stay in memory when home button is pressed.

Comment: Are you using `AssetManager` for your resources ?

Comment: I'm using an AssetManager and a TextureAtlas.

Comment: hopefully you've non static reference of `AssetManager`

Comment: The singleton class has a static instance due to it being a singleton. The AssetManager, the TextureAtlas and everything else within the class are not static.  But when pause() is called, I set everything within the class to null and I set the singleton instance to null too.  In resume() a new instance is created and all textures, music and sound are loaded back.